# RequestMapping with multiple values with pathvariable - Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/userDetails", "/userDetails/edit/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String userDetails(Map Model,****) {
//what goes here? 
}
```

What will be my arguments to the `userDetails` method? And how do I differentiate `/userDetails` and `/userDetails/edit/9` within the method?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745471/spring-web-mvc-use-same-request-mapping-for-request-parameter-and-path-variable)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ideally we can get pathvariable by using annotation `@PathVariable` in method argument but here you have used array of url `{"/userDetails", "/userDetails/edit/{id}"}` so this will give error while supply request like `localhost:8080/domain_name/userDetails` , in this case no id will be supplied to @PathVariable.

So you can get the difference (which request is comming through) by using argument HttpServletRequest request in method and use this request object as below -

String uri = request.getRequestURI();

Code is like this -

```
   @RequestMapping(value = {"/userDetails", "/userDetails/edit/{id}"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public String userDetails(Map Model,HttpServletRequest request) {
   String uri = request.getRequestURI();  
  //put the condition based on uri
 }
```

Comment: I use method=RequestMethod.GET and method=RequestMethod.POST separately. In that case, I won't be passing HttpServletRequest as an argument. Is there any other way around?

Comment: why don't you separate these two requestmapping into two methods? and if you have any common functionality to implement you can put that common code in separate private method and call this method accordingly.