# Optional path segments in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Reading [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-3-webmvc-optional-path) (Spring 3) article from 2010, it discusses using an extension to provide a convenient way to include optional path segments:

```
@RequestMapping("/houses/[preview/][small/]{id}")
public String handlePreview(@PathVariable long id, @PathVariable("preview/") boolean preview, @PathVariable("small/") boolean small) {
    return "view";
}
```

I know I could just implement a number of request mappings to achieve the same effect:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/houses/preview/{id}")
...

@RequestMapping(value="/houses/{id}")
...
~~~ snip ~~~
```

But depending on the number of possible permutations, it seems like a very verbose option.

Does any later version of Spring (after 3) provide such a facility? Alternatively, is there any mechanism to chain portions of the request URL to feed a larger response method signature?

**Update**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745471/spring-web-mvc-use-same-request-mapping-for-request-parameter-and-path-variable#2746361) to a question relating to sharing path variables and request parameters suggests an approach like:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value={"/campaigns","/campaigns/{id}"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String getCampaignDetails(
         @PathVariable("id") String id)
    {
        ~~~ snip ~~~
```

But the path variable cannot be set to null. Just going to `/campaigns` will return a 400 response.

Comment: Do you want like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745471/spring-web-mvc-use-same-request-mapping-for-request-parameter-and-path-variable#2746361

Comment: Nearly, Javi's answer with the multiple request values - `value={"/campaigns","/campaigns/{id}"}` is very nearly there, but I'd like to map fixed segments in the URL.

Comment: this question already discussed on one forum, this is same asked here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-3-webmvc-optional-path

Comment: Yes, that's the article I link to in my question... hence why I'm asking for alternatives. ;)

Comment: If all else fails, you could always rewrite the URLs with filter like this one: http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

Comment: What about `/houses/**/{id}`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With Spring 3.0, can I make an optional path variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904092/with-spring-3-0-can-i-make-an-optional-path-variable)

Comment: @OlegEstekhin The link and body of my question already acknowledged the approach in the question you've linked to. My question is asking for alternatives in later versions of spring (have edited to make that clearer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why you don't use `java.util.Optional` if you are using `Java 1.8`. To take your later example, you can avert a 400 response with put a `Optional<String>` instead of `String` representing your eventualy path like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value={"/campaigns","/campaigns/{id}"})
@ResponseBody
public String getCampaignDetails(
     @PathVariable("id") Optional<String> id)
{ 
  if(id.isPresent()){
      model.addAttribute("id", id.get());//id.get() return your String path
  }
}
```