# Optional in path param in REST api Spring MVC

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, option-type, spring-4

I have requirement to pass a Optional parameter (count) to GET method. I tried below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/findDetail","/findDetail/{no}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
     public int findAll(@PathVariable Optional<Integer>  no) {
        //find method takes Optional argument.
        return ticketService.find(no);
    }
```

I am expecting some value here but no always has null. Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this out, and it worked fine for me? `no.get()` gives 4 with a `GET` to `/findDetail/4`

I'm running with Spring MVC 4.2.6 (via Spring Boot 1.3.5) if that makes any difference?

Do you see a change if you do `@PathVariable("no") Optional<Integer>  no` instead? (I can't see why you would, but worth a shot?)

But you definitely are on the right 'path' - what you said should work fine as pointed at in [Optional path segments in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36594351/6345090) amongst other answers.

Comment: I tried with same Spring version as yours. I have deployed it in tomcat. While running in debug mode to check the value, I am not at all the value

Comment: Hmm okay. Could you try changing the signature to `public int findAll(@PathVariable Optional<Integer>  no, HttpServletRequest request) {` and seeing what Spring thinks the URL is in debug mode? (`request.getRequestURL()`)

Comment: Actually when I give multiple value in Request mapping, it doesnt work. The call even doesnt come to method. But when I give single value like value = "/findDetail/ or value = "/findDetail/{no}, it works as expected for that url.