# Can Spring be directed to take a parameter from either the body or the URL?

Tags: spring-mvc

An argument to a Spring MVC method can be declared as RequestBody or RequestParam. Is there a way to say, "Take this value from either the body, if provided, or the URL parameter, if not"? That is, give the user flexibility to pass it either way which is convenient for them.

Answer (score 1):

You can make both variables and check them both for null later on in your code
like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = GET_SOMETHING, params = {"page"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
JSONObject getPromoByBusinessId(
        @PathVariable("businessId") String businessId, @RequestParam("page") int page,
        @RequestParam("valid") Boolean valid,
        @RequestParam("q") String promoName) throws Exception {}
```

and then use a series if if-else to react to requests.
I wrote it to work with any of the three params be null or empty, react to all different scenarios.

To make them optional, see :
[Spring Web MVC: Use same request mapping for request parameter and path variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745471/spring-web-mvc-use-same-request-mapping-for-request-parameter-and-path-variable)

Answer (score 1):

HttpServletRequest interface should help solve this problem

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getInfo",method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String getInfo(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String name=request.getParameter("name");
    return name;

}
```

Now, based on request data coming from body or parameter the value will be picked up

```
C:\Users\sushil
λ curl http://localhost:8080/getInfo?name=sushil-testing-parameter
sushil-testing-parameter
C:\Users\sushil
λ curl -d "name=sushil-testing-requestbody" http://localhost:8080/getInfo
sushil-testing-requestbody
C:\Users\sushil
λ
```